# .getElementByClassName not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone: I'm having difficulty getting this code to work:

HTML:

```
        <div id='nav_bar'>
       <ul id="ul">
<li onmouseover="test();" > <a href='friends.php' class="first"  >Friends</a>                       </li>
          <li onmouseover="test();"> <a href='messages.php' class="first">Messages</a>              </li>
          <li onmouseover="test();"> <a href='index.php' class="first">Home</a>                     </li>
          <li onmouseover="test();"> <a href='profile.php?id=<?= $prof ?>' class="first">Profile</a></li>
          <li onmouseover="test();"> <a href='find_friends.php' class="first">Search</a>            </li>
          <li onmouseover="test();"> <a href='members.php' class="first">Members</a>                </li>
          <li onmouseover="test();"> <a href='logout.php' class="first">Log Out</a>                 </li>

       </ul>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    function test(){
x = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
x.style.backgroundColor = "#ee7600";
x.style.border = "thin solid black";
}
```

The Javascript file is correctly referenced by the HTML file; I'm attempting to change the style of each element with class="first" in a nav bar. Why won't `document.getElementsByClass()` work?

Comment: I really hope this is a contrived example and you're not actually using JavaScript to set styles on elements which have a particular class.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like live *HTMLCollection*.

`style` is a property of a single *HTMLElement*.

Loop over the HTML Collection and modify the style of each one in turn.

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ee7600";
    x[i].style.border = "thin solid black";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. For your example, try looping through and accessing each element in the loop `getElementsByClassName("first")[index]`.

Comment: It returns an HTML Collection, not an array.

Comment: @Quentin Didn't know that, thanks :)